# Angular UI Grid : render image if it exist on a separate server otherwise set a default image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid, angular-directive

I am using Angular UI Grid and I have looked up several stack overflow and other blogs but still can't seem to solve the problem. I have a directive, but still getting nowhere.

**Problem**

I'd like to render an image on UI Grid table if it exists on a separate server otherwise set it to a default image. I have built a custom directive and injected that directive on a UI grid columnDefs. I have my directive show default images if there is an error. The problem is it is not showing the images which are available on existing server.

I have attached my Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDHI3cfUWaa7NllGXZeL. Plunkr doesn't seem to be working, but my actual code is. I want to share all the relevant code so you have all the necessary code on Plunkr.

**PS.** I need to prepend a prefix url (www.bucketfeet.com) on my profile_image_url to get the image. However, some URLs are cloud front URLs (http://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net) which is their CDN. If it starts with http:// I don’t need to prepend http://www.bucketfeet.com. Otherwise, I do.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('imageRender', function () {
    var imageRenderTableView = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<img width=20px src="http://google.com/favicon.ico" ng-src="www.bucketfeet.com/{{data.profile_image_url}}">',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var defaultSrc = attrs.src;
              element.bind('error', function() {
                if(defaultSrc) {
                    element.attr('src', defaultSrc);
                }
                else if(attrs.ngSrc) {
                    element.attr('ngSrc', attrs.ngSrc);
                }
          });
        }
    }
    return imageRenderTableView;
});
```

Insert directive in columnDefs

```
{name:'img', width: 50, cellTemplate:"<image-render></image-render>", enableSorting: false}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

**My Screen**
[image]
**See Plunkr for JSON and how I am retrieving data on Angular Service.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem. The problem I was trying to solve was to render images in Angular Ui-Grid table if they exist on an external server. Otherwise, show a default image.

You have to use **row.entity.FIELDNAME**. In my case, it was row.entity.profile_image_url since that is what is on my object property.

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('imageRender', function () {
    var imageRenderTableView = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<img width=20px src="imgs/art.jpg" ng-src="{{row.entity.profile_image_url}}">',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var defaultSrc = attrs.src;
              element.bind('error', function() {
                if(defaultSrc) {
                    element.attr('src', defaultSrc);
                }
                else if(attrs.ngSrc) {
                    element.attr('ngSrc', attrs.ngSrc);
                }
          });
        }
    }
    return imageRenderTableView;
});
```

You pass in directive as a HTML attribute in your column defs in your Angular UI Table. See below:

```
columnDefs: [
            {name:'img', width: 50, cellTemplate:"<image-render></image-render>", enableSorting: false},
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

**PS- Part Two**
I added prefix to my profile_image_url by using plain javascript concat method by running a forEach method through my array of objects.

Hope this helps if someone is ever looking into rendering images dynamically on Angular UI Grid. Angular directive is a way to go!!!!

Comment: Do all the images have the same height? I don't think it is possible to render images with different heights in ui-grid? The row height doesn't adjust automatically depending on size of image.

Comment: @ SaiGiridhar They all have the same height. I don't think you can render different heights for different images.